# UIPageViewController handle didFinishAnimating transitionCompleted is false

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I am using UIPageViewController to swipe between two screens ..

I have a web service call for both screen in view did appear. If in didFinishAnimating method transitionCompleted is true then everything is fine but if transitionCompleted is false then also view did appear is called and web service is called but screen is not switched.

Is there any work around where I can call web service for related screen only if swipe transitionCompleted is true.

Method call sequence when didFinishAnimating transitionCompleted is true ->

1. willTransitionToViewControllers
2. viewWillAppear page 2
3. viewDidAppear page 2
4. didFinishAnimating
5. viewControllerAfterViewController
6. viewControllerBeforeViewController
7. viewControllerAfterViewController

Method call sequence when didFinishAnimating transitionCompleted is false ->

1. willTransitionToViewControllers
2. viewWillAppear page 2
3. viewWillAppear page 1
4. viewDidAppear page 1
5. didFinishAnimating

Comment: Simple solution is to have the common flag for `didFinishAnimating transitionCompleted` and handle accordingly in `viewDidAppear`

Comment: but viewDidAppear is getting called before  didFinishAnimating

Comment: In  didFinishAnimating access the current view controller and call a function to make web service call.